# tty (console): disable monitor

Tags: linux, console, monitors

In .xinitrc, I use

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
```

to disable the monitor of my laptop (I always use a projector at school).

But, before I log in with `xinit`, or when I temporary go to the console (Linux virtual terminal, for example tty2 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) -- simply put, then the monitor is on, and I'd like it to be off.

I suppose it is logical that it only works during X as xrandr is an X tool. So, I need to find the console "xrandr".

Comment: Does your laptop's display selecting key (Fn + F2 on my HP Mini 110) do anything?

Comment: On my F8, it says (in Fn font and color) "CRT/LCD" which sounds as concerning monitors, but nothing happens when I press the keys. It could be that the Fn key is not configured (I never used it, and I have a keyboard configuration based on an external keyboard) -- unless the Fn stuff is completely in the hardware. In either case, I would like it more - like the xrandr solution for X: transparent, and automatically invoked.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible. The console video driver is pretty basic. There's little point in not booting into X nowadays: I recommend booting into xdm/gdm/kdm/….

Comment: Yes, I'm not going to stop using X. The first command I give is `xinit` in 95 out of 100 cases. Still, I'd like to examine if it is possible to disable the monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, as the driver(s) used for the virtual consoles are not that flexible. Once the *fb kernel driver is loaded its settings cannot be changed and once the fbcon module is loaded the *fb wouldn't unload (for me).

However, you just want to enable/disable a monitor and not a full equivalent to xrandr on the console, I think. There is the program `vbetool` which can interact with hardware a little. Depending on your hardware this tool can enable/disable your lcd panel.

The Linux kernel documentation knows a little about this. In [Documentation/power/video.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/video.txt)  lists some alternative tools as well.

Comment: 100% correct: `sudo vbetool dpms off` shuts my laptop monitor off, but doesn't affect the projector.

Comment: I've never heard of `vbetool` - great answer!

Comment: @user1129682: Do you know how to make this option default? Or maybe how to always run it before you get to the tty login prompt? I put it in `.profile` - it works, but requires the super user password each time.

Comment: @user1129682: Never mind, found it: `/etc/rc.local`