# laptop with bad monitor turned into server: how to disable monitor

Tags: hardware, monitors

I have a laptop with an absolutly useless monitor (well, probably video card), so I put an Ubuntu 14.04 server on it. Of course if I turn it on, the monitor still turns on and blinks in vivid colors, which is annoying and a waste of electricity. How can I disable the monitor via the commandline, so it will not get powered on? Possible the videocard as well, since that is also useless.

I have only found answers related to the X11-server-utils, but those don't even find the monitor (not really suprising, as I can only connect through ssh).

Comment: Have you considered opening the laptop and disconnecting the monitor cables?

Comment: Yes I did, but I totally think this should be possible to do via the terminal, so I am trying to find out how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [tty (console): disable monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44809/tty-console-disable-monitor?rq=1).

The command line utility `vbetool` can be used to turn the monitor on or off:
`vbetool dpms off`

Answer (score 1):

```
setterm --blank 1
setterm --blank force
setterm --powersave powerdown
```

The above or perhaps a subset of them should work.

Personally, if it's really broken, I'd open the laptop and disconnect the cable running to the screen.

Comment: Yes, it would probably be easier, but this is more interesting :) So I'd would kind of like to learn how to do this.

I tried your suggestions, they all work with only one "-", but beside that the first two does nothing, the third one gives me an error:

`setterm: cannot (un)set powersave mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Comment: The combination of the first 2 should cause the screen to be turned off after 1 minute. Check the manpage to setterm. Note you need to do this on the screen itself, ssh'ing into the system and then doing this won't work. You could try `TERM=linux setterm --blank 1 > /dev/tty1` etc. (wierd that your setterm doesn't take the `--` long argument thing.)

Comment: Hmm, probably some version thing, it gives `setterm: argument error` with `--` and prints the help, and everything is with `-`. Anyway I tried putting what you gave me to `/dev/tty1`, again nothing. Maybe I should try disabling the video card.