# Turn off/on laptop display from TTY without additional software

Tags: command-line, tty, display, monitors

I have a laptop with Artix Linux on it that I'm using as a web server. I want to keep it minimalist, w/o graphical environment and only the absolute necessary software.

My problem is I still don't know how to turn off/on the display (to save energy) when I'm not interacting with it (which I do very rarely).

I am aware of these posts:

- [Turn off monitor using command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line)
- [How to turn off the monitor under TTY](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242424/how-to-turn-off-the-monitor-under-tty)

But they either talk about solutions that work for a graphical environment or they use some additional software (vbetool) that I'm not even able to install. It would also be very cool If I could turn the display off/on through ssh

Comment: Why can't you install `vbetool`? It seems to be the solution. Since it's a web server it has got access to the Internet - although you might be blocking outbound traffic. You can also download the package elsewhere, copy it to laptop and install it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found [a page in ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/backlight) that explains everything. No additional software is needed. All I have to do is change the value in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` to `0` to turn the display off. To turn it back on, I can use any value grater than `0`. The maximum value can be found in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`.

Note that the `intel_backlight` part is hardware dependent. It might be something else, like `acpi_video0` on a different machine.