# Let agetty (or other) switch off the laptop screen after a short while on non-UI linux

Tags: console, power-management, agetty

Using an older laptop as a small server with no graphical UI/login, it has an `agetty` running on the system console, i.e. the laptop screen.

Since I login almost always via network, there is no point having the screen switched on. It should be off until I hit some key. Can this be done?

The following are non-options:

- not running `agetty`, because I want to keep it as a fallback in case I cannot log in over the net anymore.
- `setterm` cannot be used, because I would have to log in first
- `setterm --blank </dev/tty1` says "terminal xterm-256color does not support --blank" :-/
- `vbetool` [linked in some answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242428/140503) wrecks the display to show garbage and cannot switch it on any more on my laptop.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234477/140503) says the console should only be started on demand, but clearly when logging in via ssh I see two agetty processes and the laptop screen is on showing the login prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Based on [this question & answers](https://superuser.com/questions/152347/change-linux-console-screen-blanking-behavior))*

This worked for me: (sets blank timeout to 1 minute)

```bash
TERM=linux setterm --blank 1 < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1
```

If you can add kernel startup commandline parameters, you can also add: (sets blank timeout to 30 seconds)

```
consoleblank=30
```

If you have Fedora, the above can be set in `/etc/default/grub` by modifying the containing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to contain the above (keeping the existing things already there), for example:

```bash
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=073539e3-5130-4a2d-883b-75214a83847c quiet consoleblank=30"
```

Then (still assuming you have Fedora) update the grub configuration file using: (as documented [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Manually_Upgrading_the_Kernel/#s3-kernel-boot-loader-grub))

```bash
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Yes, the `consoleblank` solution is what I have and it seems to work. I wish I could test whether the screen is really blanked (black, off) without lifting the lid :-/